# SVG CSS attribute animation-duration not working

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I dont know why but this CSS tag seems to be not working. I need to put "dur" on every animation tag there is. Is there a workaround or a solution?

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-duration.asp

```html
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="1080" height="1080">
    
        <style>
            div {
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-duration: 1s;
                        animation: noname 1s linear 0s 1
            }
        </style>
    
        <line x1="400" y1="400" x2="10" y2="515" stroke="hsl(250,82%,56%)" stroke-width="3">
            <animate
                attributeName="x1"
                values="50;100;200;350;400"
                calcMode="discrete"
            />
            <animate
                attributeName="y1"
                values="50;100;200;350;400"
                calcMode="discrete"
            />
            <animate
                attributeName="stroke"
                values="hsl(50,82%,56%);hsl(100,82%,56%);hsl(150,82%,56%);hsl(200,82%,56%);hsl(250,82%,56%)"
                calcMode="discrete"
            />
        </line>
    </svg>
```

Comment: In SMIL you need to use the `dur` attribute to set the duration of the animation.Please take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL

Comment: SMIL and CSS animations are not interchangeable. You need to pick one or the other, you can't mix and match.